# VisualGDB doesnt create elf files

Tags: elf, stm32, cortex-m, visualgdb

after buying the full version of VisualGDB i cannot find .elf files in new projects, and the old projects created with the TrialVersion wont open (unknown toolchain error).

I need the .elf file for STMStudio, becouse the live variables are not so good in VisualGDB.

After buying the key, VisualGDB did some upgrades, maybe i need to add just some settings.

Comment: Add the makefile of your project to your question.

Comment: Basically the output files of the make process are defined in the makefile.

Comment: I do know how to get him when i am using eclipse, but i have no Idea where do i get the makefile with VisualGDB (VisualStudio2013)

Comment: Search the project folder manually.

Comment: After some searching, the makefile will be created when the project in VisualGDB under GNU created is, but the full version does it (default) as MSBuild without makefile, so i dont have a makefile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

To have a makefile and a .elf file it is necessary to import the project under GNU or to create it under GNU, the MSBuild doesnt create any of these files.

Thanks your answers leaded to a solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it, it was a tricky stuff after all. Note that you will be able to accept you own answer after half a day.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong Answer of Michal D.
The file is created by MSBUILD.
An executable file like .elf on UNIX systems doesn't have an extension.

The .elf on VisualGDB projects will be located in the same folder where .bin is generated.

ProjectRootPath/VisualGDB/Debug/nameOfYourProject

It hasn't an extension. And probably, it will be the largest file in the folder.

Comment: Hi, yes such file is there, but it cannot be loaded into a company program like the .elf files so it is worthless, but we did migrate to Atollic and everythink works fine now...